# htaccess - rewrite rule [f,l] not working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to defend my site from spamers. I've checked logs and found a lot of things like:

```
38.87.46.132 - - [06/May/2016:19:34:40 +0200] "GET /?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=465707 HTTP/1.0" 200 11955 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
155.94.179.172 - - [06/May/2016:19:34:24 +0200] "GET /component/user/?task=register HTTP/1.0" 404 9092 "http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_user&view=register" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
155.94.179.172 - - [06/May/2016:19:34:22 +0200] "GET /index.php/component/user/?task=register HTTP/1.0" 301 670 "http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_user&view=register" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
38.87.46.132 - - [06/May/2016:19:34:40 +0200] "GET /?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=465707 HTTP/1.0" 200 11955 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
```

I've added something to htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^component/k2/itemlist/user/\d* - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^option=com_k2/\ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

but still not working, site is loading slower and slower...

Comment: I've changed `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]` but it only block example.com/?option=com_... but not for example.com/index.php?option=com_

Comment: Make sure this block rule is very first rule.

Comment: Please include your entire .htaccess file. Where is the `RewriteEngine` directive? There is no reason why `example.com/?option=com_` would be blocked, but not `example.com/index.php?option=com_` - from the rule you have posted in comments. Unless you have other directives that are conflicting.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my htaaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^component/k2/itemlist/user/\d* - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^component/k2/itemlist/\d* - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^component/user/\d* - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^component/k2/\d* - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} index.php?option=com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=register [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} index.php?action=register [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} compontent [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} index.php/compontent [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]


</IfModule>
```

But still some urls are blocked, im turning on server, and after 5 minutes is going down, because of tons of requests..